# Difference between 'git push origin master' and 'git push -u origin --all'?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I'm following [this tutorial](https://ommune.com/kb/pushing-a-new-project-directory-to-bitbucket-repository/) on pushing an existing project to Bitbucket, and it mentions using the command `git push -u origin --all`. How does this command differ from `git push origin master`?

Comment: [`git help push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `git push origin master` pushes your current branch up to the
  `master` branch on `origin`.
- `git push -u origin -all` pushes *all*
  branches to origin.  The `-u` option sets up your local branches to
  track the remote branches.  This essentially establishes a link between your local branch, and the branch on the remote repository.  Without doing this if you switch to one of these branches and do a `git push` you'll be greeted with an error message `fatal: The current branch <branch-name> has no upstream branch.` You can check the branch link by command `git branch -vv`.

**Summary**: `git push -u origin -all` pushes *all* branches to origin, `git push origin master` pushes your current branch up to the `master` branch on origin.

Comment: Middle ground is `git push -u origin master`, which pushes & tracks only a single branch.